# get parse object from userList android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am little bit confused to resolve this error. I want to search email Id from Parse and check it either this email Id already exists there or not, if it exists there then it will give toast message to the user otherwise it will be create the account and it's data will be save on Parse. But, I am getting an error my data is not searching from Parse and not showing my desire result.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AppUser");
                            query.whereEqualTo("email", emailstr);
                            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(List<ParseObject> userList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        if (userList.size() == 0) {

                                            saveUserOnParse(user);
                                        }else{

                                            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this, "This email is already exist here, You must enter another email for SIGN UP.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                            temp.show();
                                        }


                                } else {
                                    }
                                }



                            });
```

I want to search email if current email is not existing in the userList then save user on parse. Please anybody help me, how can I do it.

Comment: The problem is "userList.size() == 0" this if condition is not working properly. Basically I want to get parse object from userList and get email form parse object. Then, I will check either this email existing or not.

Comment: I think you want to do a query for ParseUser rather than ParseObject.

Comment: yes, or I want to get email from ParseUser.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I have done solve my problem by using this code.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FileName");
                            query.whereEqualTo("email", user.getEmail());
                            query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(int count, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null){
                                        if (count == 0){
                                            saveUserOnParse(user);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this, "This email is already exist here, You must enter another email for SIGN UP.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                            temp.show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast temp = Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this, e+ "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        temp.show();
                                    }
                                }


                            });
```